# pyBAMM package not available in conda forge channel but its there in thier website

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, anaconda3, conda-forge

Hi I was trying to install a python package pyBAMM which will be required for an online course that will start in coming weeks. But when I try to install through Anaconda navigator or through terminal commands it says package not found from current channels. Though I have added conda forge channel.
Though one thing i noticed in thier Git hub page its written that PyBaMM is available on GNU/Linux, MacOS and Windows. But in their conda page under files tab there is not file for windows. Can you help how to install pybamm package. I will be running it in jupyter notebook only. [pyBAMM files tab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opR9O.png). [Error description in anaconda prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGEXV.png)

Comment: On their github packge, both `conda install` and `pip install` are mentioned. Have you tried the altter?

Comment: Yes I'm able to install it through pip. But as I feel comfortable working with anaconda I was looking for conda package.

Comment: As you have already noticed though, it is [not available for windows](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pybamm) from conda-forge and no other conda channel has this package. It is not explicitly mentioned on their github page, but [this issue](https://github.com/pybamm-team/PyBaMM/issues/904) mentions that they failed to provide a windows conda package due to dependencies not being available. So I am afraid you are out of luck looking for a `conda` package. there is nothing wrong with pip installing it to a new env though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyBaMM is now available as a conda package through the conda-forge channel on Windows, macOS, and Linux.

You can install it by using
`conda install -c conda-forge pybamm`

If you face any issues, please feel free to create a new issue in the repository [here](https://github.com/pybamm-team/PyBaMM/issues).